# Kubuntu 22.04 dist upgrade disabled mouse

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, touchpad

I was offered by the system upgrade from Kubuntu 20.04 to Kubuntu 22.04 and after that was done the touchpad became unresponsive. How can I bring it back to life? The machine is Aspire 5.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked, including right settings, but simple Ctrl+F7 brought it to life.